# Excel VBA to compare string of one column to string of second column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will compare the first 4 characters of one column to the first 4 characters of another column in the same row and then mark that row as either Match or No Match.

I did some research and found an Excel formula (=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT(A2,4)&"*",B2:B2,0)),"No Match","Match") which works but I'm not sure how to convert this to VBA. The spreadsheets I'm working with can vary in row length from day to day but they would always have the same number of columns. So I need to be able to: compare column C to column F and write the Match / No Match outcome to column G regardless of the number of rows on the spreadsheet.

Here is an example of the spreadsheet I'm working with that shows the outcome of using the Excel formula.

Any help / suggestions you can provide would be appreciated.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbDij.jpg)

Comment: you can use Conditional Formatting on the column to highlight the no match cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simplified formula and convert it to values if needed (works for active sheet).

```
Sub CompareLeft()
  Dim LRow As Long
  LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  With Range("c2:c" & LRow)  '<-- Adjust result column
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(RC1,4)=LEFT(RC2,4),""Match"",""No Match"")"
    .Value = .Value '<-- Optional - convert formula to values
  End With
End Sub
```